# callStateChanged not working in background?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

Below is the code,

```
func handleCall()
    {
        self.callCenter!.callEventHandler = {(call: CTCall) -> Void in
            if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
            {
                    self.someAction()
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Where I am performing some action when a call is connected, it works fine the foreground, but not in the background.If I enable `VoIP` feature in `UIBackgroundModeKey` in Capabilities, the event will get called in the background too, but unfortunately the app will get rejected.Is there a way to receive call state when app is in `UIBackground` mode?